# How can I trim url with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have url

```
http://example.com/root/22.php
```

And want trim with .htaccess to

```
 http://example.com/22.php
```

with obtaining the same data

How can I do that?

Comment: Is **root/** a directory?

Comment: What do you mean by `path of route`? Are you using any CMS/PHP framework here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+root/([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/root/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /root/$1 [L]
```

Comment: When I go to url [http://xn----8sb3aobdifmb0d.xn--p1ai/sorevnovania/filter/22] is trimmed in http://xn----8sb3aobdifmb0d.xn--p1ai/22 but return 404 error. My code: `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+sorevnovania/filter/([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sorevnovania/filter/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sorevnovania/filter/$1 [L]`

Comment: @AlexanderKolovsky Try changing the `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sorevnovania/filter/$1 -f` line to `RewriteCond $1 !^sorevnovania/filter/`